# Drag/Drop events return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to do an inventory system for a RPG. I want an user to be able to drag an item from their inventory and drop it into a character slot and equip it.

```
this.dragItem = function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}
```

The element I intended to drag is

```
$('<div>', {
    class: 'HUDInventoryItem',
    id: `${i}`,
    draggable: 'true',
    ondragstart: 'inventoryWindow.dragItem()'
}).appendTo('#inventoryWindowItems');
```

I used `dragItem()` to get the data andthe first error that I got when I dragged an item was

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined

I added `console.log(event)` to see the event object, and it returns an undefined object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in the event to the function. Try this:

```
$('<div>', {
    class: 'HUDInventoryItem',
    id: `${i}`,
    draggable: 'true',
    ondragstart: 'inventoryWindow.dragItem(event)'
}).appendTo('#inventoryWindowItems');
```